# JavaFX| Location not set (After reinstall)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

So everything was working just fine before the reinstall. I pushed to git naturally then I reinstalled my OS. After the reinstall, when I try to run the JavaFx application, I get the `IllegalStateExceptionL: Location is not set`

Is there any reason why this is happening? It worked before and now it isn't. My folder structure is like this:

```
src:
   main:
       java:
           com.package:
                      Launcher.java
       resources:
           com.package:
                      main.fxml
```

And this is how I get the resource in my `Launcher.java` class:

```
  URL resource = getClass().getResource("main.fxml");
```

What I've tried:

When I `sout` the resource, (obviously) `null` is returned.
I have also checked and verified that my `resources` is marked as the resources root in `Project Structure`.

I have also tried changing the path to `/main.fxml` but this doesn't work also.
I feel like I shouldn't be even changing the code and maybe Intellij is missing something? But anyways I'm just confused as to why this is happening all of a sudden. Not sure if this is a duplicate since its a common error but I want to know why it just stopped working.

Any help would be appreciated

(The only thing that's changed from the previous set up is the Java version. I was on JDK14 previously and I'm using 15 now.)

The stacktrace is :

````
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at MyApplication.main/com.package.Launcher.start(Launcher.java:21)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.package.Launcher

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Launcher.main()'.```
````

Comment: Check the content of the build folder.

Comment: Please share the stacktrace. Also, we don't know what  "the" JavaFX application is so relevant code would help.

Comment: @James_D the build folder shows the file `build -> resources -> main -> com -> package -> main.fxml`

Comment: @MichelJung I made an edit with the stacktrace. As for the code, its just the main Launcher for my application. I can show the class too but its just your regular JavaFX FXML loading for the `main` method

Comment: Is your project a Java module? If so, `getClass().getResource("main.fxml")` might not work (I can't explain why). And is your project started via Gradle?

Comment: The build looks wrong to me. `Launcher.class` should be in the same folder (in the build/output structure) as `main.fxml`?.

Comment: @MichelJung yes it is a Gradle modular project. It was working before though

Comment: @James_D Anything I can do to rectify the build?

Comment: I'd clean and rebuild it first. Then check gradle settings (I'm not a gradle user).

Comment: Just tried that, no dice. Are you on Maven? I can try switching to it and see if it compiles

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using? Can you share your `build.gradle[.kts]` file? And to clarify, does your code have a `module-info.java` file?

Comment: @Slaw here's the `build.gradle` file from the [repo](https://github.com/kawaki-san/DigitalAssistant/blob/master/build.gradle). And yes, I have a `module-info.java` file. Grade is `gradle-6.5.1-all`